# SharePoint 2010 throws an unexpected error when setting target audience

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, audience-targeting

An unexpected error is thrown when a navigation item's target audience is created and/or modified.  This is a new problem, as I have been using audience targeting for a while without any problem.  I have used IE9 32 and 64-bit browsers, both give the same error.

Any assistance in what may be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of target audience error message]

Comment: Have you checked the actual error message in the ULS logs? That's where you need to start!

Comment: I tried looking in the "C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS" folder.  However, there is no "LOGS" folder or log files any any of the folders sub- to "Web Server Extensions".

Comment: The the log files is configured to be stored somewhere else, does the server have a second hard drive partition? If so, poke atriums for logs on that drive :)

Comment: are you able to fix it? if not whats in the ULS logs?You can run the merge-splogfile command with correlation id will get the log entries from all servers.

Comment: I found that the problem only occurs with Internet Explorer 9.  I was able to set the target audience with Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox without any problem.  I checked and double-checked the Internet settings on both computers (IE8 vs IE9) and they are both configured the same.  So, I have found a "work-around", but still do not know why the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the site not being added to Internet Explorer's local intranet zone for some reason. (are you using https protocol?)  Try going to Tools>Internet Options:

- Select the Security Tab
- Click Local intranet, then click sites
- Click Advanced
- Click add to add the site to the local intranet zone

Doing this resolved this issue for me in Internet Explorer.